# Problem about latex bibitem output (version used in the Journal's template is different from generated ones)

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, bibitem

I already created a .bib file for my references. However, now, I need to convert them to bibitems in the main .tex file such as

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{article1} ...
\bibitem{article2} ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

So, I used an [online bibtex to bibitem converter](https://asouqi.github.io/bibtex-converter/) to do that and for example, for my one reference, bibtex was

```
@article{dash2019big,
  title={Big data in healthcare: management, analysis and future prospects},
  author={Dash, Sabyasachi and Shakyawar, Sushil Kumar and Sharma, Mohit and Kaushik, Sandeep},
  journal={Journal of Big Data},
  volume={6},
  number={1},
  pages={1--25},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

And generated bibitem for mentioned reference is

```
\bibitem{dash2019big}Dash, S., Shakyawar, S., Sharma, M. \& Kaushik, S. Big data in healthcare: management, analysis and future prospects. {\em Journal Of Big Data}. \textbf{6}, 1-25 (2019)
```

This generates the following output in my pdf file

```
Dash, S., Shakyawar, S., Sharma, M. & Kaushik, S. Big data in healthcare: management, analysis and future prospects. *Journal Of Big Data.* **6**, 1-25 (2019)
```

So the **problem** starts at that point. In the template that we need to follow, both bibitem and the generated pdf output are different (especially abbreviations of name and surnames) from what I generated. In the template (I need to do mine also as follows), an example of bibitem:

```
\bibitem{7}
\newblock J. Serrin,
\newblock Gradient estimates for solutions of nonlinear elliptic and parabolic equations,
\newblock in \emph{Contributions to Nonlinear Functional Analysis}, Academic Press, 1971, 33-75.
```

An example of generated pdf output for that bibitem:

```
[7] J. Serrin, Gradient estimates for solutions of nonlinear elliptic and parabolic equations, in *Contributions to Nonlinear Functional Analysis*, Academic Press, 1971, 33-75.
```

Note that the .bst and .cls files are similar in the template and in my work. I do not understand if there are some different versions of bibitem (if yes I could not find one) or if there is something else. I am stuck at that point. Could you please give me an idea about how can I convert my references appropriately according to the given template? I can also write all of them manually but I have lots of references and it would be tedious/time-consuming to do.

Journal that I am talking about is [JIMO](https://www.aimsciences.org/journal/1547-5816)

Comment: Why are you using an online converter to convert your bibtex database to bibitems? That's what BibTeX is for. Get rid of the `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` environment and just use `\bibliographystyle{nameofbstfile}\bibliography{nameofbibfile}`. BibTeX generates the bibitems according to the specified style and puts them in the .bbl file which is read by that command.

Comment: I guess that online conversion site does have a "add custom style" option; maybe you could upload the .bst file and it would work, but it makes more sense to me just to use bibtex.

Comment: converting bib files to bibitem is _all_ bibtex does. Why can you not use bibtex?